# How to invalidate a JWT token while changing scopes on server side

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, scopes, clientcredential

I am implementing the oauth2 client credentials flow. When Auth server is called to get token... I return a jwt token including also scopes into it (e.g. read:orders and write:orders) and as audience the api identifier (.. /serv/api/v1/orders). When I use then token I pass it in authentication header as Bearer token. When I check if token is valid I check expire date.. If the API called is the same of audience and if the endpoint called has a scope included in my token.  If server side I delete scope (e.g. I remove write:order scope) the previous token also contains the write scope. Actually the only thing I do is to wait token fails and when I get a new token I will don't have the write scope.

How can I invalidate the previous token before expiration?
Should I check scope server side during token validation? In this case I suppose is useless to register scopes into token.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to invalidate tokens before expiration date then you have to keep track of the issued tokens in your Authorization Server, mark those which should be invalidated, and then make the API verify the token by making a request to the Authorization Server.

As you've pointed out, in such a setup there is not much use of the scopes in the token. I would suggest to use an opaque token instead of a JWT as your access token. Then have your API perform token introspection - which is a standardised operation in OAuth. The Authorization Server will return scopes corresponding to your token, or 404 if the token has been invalidated.